# can't see my third party joomla website on localhost

Tags: joomla, localhost, config

I cannot see my Joomla website on localhost.
The browser gives me the error: **Error de HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error)**
It's a third party website, so I revised .htaccess and I decided to change its name to htaccessOLD so as to try to solve the problem, but no... :(
I revised the configuration.php but everything seems to be fine (/tmp and /logs paths)

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a look at the server error log that is in the /logs folder to find out why the server is throwing an internal server error.

It's more than likely that it's something to do with your php configuration. If you can create a file called phpinfo.php and put this as the content:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Save it to the www or htdocs folder and visit `http://localhost/phpinfo.php` you should see a page that gives you all the php configuration information.

If you get another HTTP 500 error, then you need to find the error log, otherwise it's more likely a problem with the Joomla installation.

Comment: I added this file, and I can see it properly.

Comment: In the /logs directory there's only one index.html with the code: <html><body bgcolor="#FFFFFF"></body></html>

Comment: What web server software are you using, and what operating system?

Comment: I'm using apache and windows xp...I just asked in joomla official forum, and answered me that maybe is because of Search Engine Friendly URLs